# 'bert-serving-start' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, nlp, conda

this is a very silly question.....I am following the [documentation of bert-as-service](https://bert-as-service.readthedocs.io/en/latest/section/get-start.html#installation) to install it. I have python 3.6.6, tensorflow 1.12.0, doing everything in conda environment, Windows 10.

I pip installed bert-serving-server/client and it shows 
`Successfully installed GPUtil-1.4.0 bert-serving-client-1.7.2 bert-serving-server-1.7.2 pyzmq-17.1.2`

but when I run the following as CLI
`bert-serving-start -model_dir /tmp/english_L-12_H-768_A-12/ -num_worker=4`
it says
`'bert-serving-start' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

I don't know where look at to fix this, can anyone help me?

I found bert-serving library is located under C:\Users\Name\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages.
So I tried to run `bert-serving-start` again under these three folders:

1. site-packages
2. site-packages\bert_serving
3. site-packages\bert_serving_server-1.7.2.dist-info

However, the result is same as not recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved on github, please check here if you have same problem:

https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service/issues/194#issuecomment-455009437

Answer (score 0):

The CLI doesn't found the application 'bert-serving-start'.

Take a look in your Python36/Scripts-folder.
The application bert-serving-start should be there (besides "pip" etc.).

Open the CLI in **this** folder and try it again.

Comment: Hi Koala, thank you. I found the bert_serving_client is installed under anaconda, so I navigated to be under that folder and run it again, but the result is same as not recognized.....The screen shot is not working, I will edit the post.